# Replace number in string - C#

Tags: c#

I have a string(numbers only) and I want to replace a specific number with `string.Empty`. I am using `string.Replace` but the issue is it replaces the given number from all numbers. I've also tried `Regex.Replace` but getting same result.

For example,

Code:

```
string original = "301, 3301, 2301, 5301, 8301";
string modified = original.Replace("301", string.Empty);
string usingRegex = Regex.Replace(original, "301", string.Empty);
```

Actual Result:

```
", 3, 2, 5, 8"
```

Expected Result:

```
"3301, 2301, 5301, 8301"
```

Comment: Split on `, `, remove the ones you don't want (easy with LINQ), then `string.Join` the rest back together.

Comment: You have a string of numbers?  Why not split this into an array of integers?

Comment: convert them all to numbers and get rid of 301 .. that should work right?

Comment: Regex is probably overkill for such a simple case

Comment: @zimdanen That's what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string original = "301, 3301, 2301, 5301, 8301, 301";
var lst = original.Split (',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(item => item != "301");
var replaced = string.Join(", ", lst);
```

This splits the string, and removes only those entries that are exactly 301, and joins back up the result. This is broadly a process of [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_%28lexical_analysis%29).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string usingRegex = Regex.Replace(original, "(^301 ,|, 301)", string.Empty);
```

This matches a 301 that ends with `,` or ends with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with \b in your Regex
something like this:

```
string original = "301, 3301, 2301, 5301, 8301";
string modified = original.Replace("301", string.Empty);
string usingRegex = Regex.Replace(original, @"\b301\b", string.Empty);
```

let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
string pattern = @"\b301\b";
string input = "301, 3301, 2301, 5301, 8301";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.None).TrimStart(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice, but working and with Regex.
Deletes (!) any number from the given string.

```
string original = "301, 3301, 2301, 5301, 8301";
string usingRegex = Regex.Replace(original, "(, 5301)*(^5301, )*", "");
Console.WriteLine(original);
Console.WriteLine(usingRegex);
```